# Fill (update) in missing values in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2016

This is a small selection from my product table. I need to add the PLU_code value to products that have PLU_code 0, but in such a way that the new value fills an empty gap in the order. For example, Product 8 will have a PLU_code of 2, product 9 - 4, product 10 - 5, etc.

| ID | SKU_code | name | PLU_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11584 | AB1234 | product 1 | 1 |
| 11659 | AB4321 | product 2 | 3 |
| 11660 | ED-7044 | product 3 | 9 |
| 11661 | Z2854 | product 4 | 10 |
| 11825 | 7703311 | product 5 | 29 |
| 11826 | 7703852 | product 6 | 146 |
| 11882 | 7707698 | product 7 | 147 |
| 11965 | 992431 | product 8 | 0 |
| 11966 | 992432 | product 9 | 0 |
| 11999 | CB35208 | product 10 | 0 |

I found a similar problem in this forum, but it was solved in a way that I don't like. I have a condition that the product table cannot be deleted and recreated. I can only update. Those PLU_code values that already exist must be preserved.

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: So what's wrong with an `UPDATE` here? I don't see any reason why you would need to `DROP` and re`CREATE` the table at all; a single `UPDATE` statement would be all you need.

Comment: Is this a one-time "stand alone" fix, or do you need to build it into your system? The reason for my question is to check whether several clients would need to run such UPDATE at the same time.

Comment: I found a similar problem here and it was solved by creating a new table. That's why I wrote that I don't want such a solution.

Comment: I need a one time fix.

Comment: I think it will not be easy in SQL Server 2016. In other systems (and in SQL Server 2022) you can generate a series of numbers which you could have used in your update logic. Hope someone has a good solution for you!

Comment: If you don't want to create a temp table of spare PLU_code you can use a CTE for that.

Comment: @Radovan. Is it a requirement to fill the gaps? An easier way might be to create a `sequence` which starts at the max(PLU) value you currently have in that table and use that in your update statements.

Comment: @Vvdl That is also a solution. But I will only use this when I don't find a solution to fill in the gaps. :)

Comment: I found a similar problem with a solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744957/fill-in-missing-values-in-a-table-in-sql)
However, I need to modify it to `UPDATE` my table. I can't figure it out... I'm self-taught in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a Tally to generate the values you need, and then use an `UPDATE`able CTE to `UPDATE` the rows which have a value of `0` for `PLU_CODE`.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@End bigint, @StartAtOne bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @StartAtOne = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@End)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
GO

DECLARE @Max int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable); --This might be better done using the sys objects though

WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT T.I,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.I) AS RN
    FROM fn.Tally(@Max, 1) T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                      WHERE T.I = YT.PLU_Code)),
RNs AS(
    SELECT PLU_Code,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.PLU_Code = 0)
UPDATE RNs
SET PLU_Code = T.I
FROM RNs
     JOIN Tally T ON RNs.RN = T.RN;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DtKGAHgm)